# Return first 100 letters from database field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

In my database MYDB i have a table called MYTABLE and inside it I have a column called NAME. I want to only return the first 100 characters of the column NAME. (NAME can be up to 2000 characters).

How can this be done in SQL as I want to set the first 100 characters to a ASP.NET label.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of column nvarchar, varchar, ntext, text, char or nchar?

Comment: Yeah, was a easy question now that I see how easy it actually is!

Comment: I added another answer with extra dots to show that there's more text available than shown ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select left(NAME, 100) as Name, ... from MYTABLE...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`LEFT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) function, e.g.

```
SELECT LEFT(mt.NAME, 100) AS SHORTNAME FROM MYTABLE mt
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Substring:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME, 1, 100) AS [ShortName] 
FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT SUBSTRING( NAME, 0 , 100 )
    FROM MYTABLE

Comment: Substring has a 1-based indexer, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME, 1, 100) AS LABEL FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`LEFT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) function:

```
SELECT LEFT(NAME, 100) AS NAME FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

I like it with dots to show that there is more text

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN LEN(NAME) <= 100 THEN NAME
    ELSE LEFT(NAME, 97) + '...'
  END SHORTNAME
FROM TABLE
```